# jsDoc: The Class constructor src line number points to Class declaration, not the constructor

Tags: class, constructor, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I like placing my static methods at the top of my Classes followed by the ctor and methods.

But the jsDoc line number for the constructor of the class points to the top of the class rather than the constructor function. Even using `@constructor` does not help.

Is there a way to force jsDoc to point to the ctor, not the class declaration?

Ex: The source file

```js
import util from './util.js'

/**
 * Subclass of Array with convenience methods used by NetLogo.
 * Typically the items in the array are Objects but can be any type.
 */
class AgentArray extends Array {
  /**
   * Convert an existing Array to an AgentArray "in place".
   * Use array.slice() if a new array is wanted
   *
   * @static
   * @param {Array} array Array to convert to AgentArray
   * @return {AgentArray} array converted to AgentArray
   */
  static fromArray(array) {
      const aarray = Object.setPrototypeOf(array, AgentArray.prototype)
      return aarray
  }

  /**
   * Creates an instance of AgentArray. Simply pass-through to super()
   * now, but may add initialization code later.
   * @param {*} args Zero or more items in Array
   * @example
   * let aa = new AgentArray({x:0,y:0}, {x:0,y:1}, {x:1,y:0})
   *  //=>  [{ x: 0, y: 0 }, { x: 0, y: 1 }, { x: 1, y: 0 }]
   */
  constructor(...args) {
      super(...args)
      // maybe do some initialization later
  }

}
```

The jsDoc html file:
[image]

Note that the ctor is on line 7 .. which is:
[image]